# How to check if number is greater than a number on ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image: screenshot]).

Stackblitz:

Please check: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-vc9lg5

I have a number `Total expense` and  a table of data.

There's a column `Amt`. The column contains advance paid which can be deducted and paid to current expense(1000) by entering in the input box next to `Amt`.

As you can see in the third column, I have entered 500, now I can enter 500 in the first row(or 100 in the second and 400 in the first row).

On `ng-change` of an input box I check if the amount entered is greater than balance deductible from the total expense by calculating `deductedTillNow` and `balanceLeftInExpense`.

You can see in the chrome extension, values of `$scope` variables `deductedTillNow` and `balanceLeftInExpense` on the right side. When I try to deduct the remaining 500 from the first row by entering `50`, the `balanceLeftInExpense` becomes 450.

So my validation does not allow to enter the next number since the next digit I try to enter after `50`, `0`, the `balanceLeftInExpense` is `450` and 500 is greater than 450. How do I allow 500 to be entered?

```
 //calculate amount till now
$scope.deductedTillNow = 0;
for (let j = 0; j < $scope.amountLedgerListArray.length; j++) {
   if($scope.amountLedgerListArray[j].adjustAmount){
    $scope.deductedTillNow = $scope.amountLedgerListArray[j].adjustAmount + $scope.deductedTillNow;
   }
}

//calculate balance left in expense

$scope.balanceLeftInExpense = $scope.totalExpenseAmount - $scope.deductedTillNow;
```

Check if amount entered is greater than `balanceLeftInExpense` - The VAlidation:

```
if(item.adjustAmount > $scope.balanceLeftInExpense){
  item.adjustAmount = item.adjustAmount.toString();
  item.adjustAmount = item.adjustAmount.substring(0, item.adjustAmount.length - 1);
  item.adjustAmount = parseInt(item.adjustAmount);
}
```

The html:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Payment Ref no</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Amt</th>
         <th >Adjust amount</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in amountLedgerListArray">
         <td>
            {{item.payment_ref_no}}
         </td>
         <td>
            {{item.payment_date}}
         </td>
         <td>
            {{item.amount}}
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="number" name="sgst" class="form-control"
               ng-disabled="item.isDisabled" autocomplete="off"
               ng-change="calculateBalanceAndRestrict(item)"
               ng-class="{'borderRedError' : expense.$invalid}"
               ng-model="item.adjustAmount" onkeypress="limitKeyPress(this, 10, event)" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

**Edit**:
The data in Amt column are Advance amounts that are already paid. Now there is a expense(1000 in this example. See screenshot `Total expense:1000`).  I can deduct from any of the rows in `Amt` column.

Here I have deducted 500 from the third row(Balance now:500). I can deduct remaining 500 from the top two rows . Either 100 from second row(since it has only 100) and then remaining 500 from first row OR the remaining 500 from first row.

I validate like this: On change of an input box, I check if the amount being entered is greater than sum of all amounts entered(`deductedTillNow`).  When I start typing in first row now, the balance left in expense is calculated. When I type 50, the balance left is 450(1000 - 500(third row) + 50(first row)).

When I type 0 after 50 for the remaining 500 in first row, balance left is 450. So my validation does not allow this(500 typed is greater than 450). I need to allow 500 to be typed.

Comment: So, what's the problem with current code?

Comment: @Justcode my validation does not allow to enter 0 after 50 for the remaining 500, because the `balanceInExpense` is now 450 by the time I type `50`

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Justcode i dont have the time. i take only 10 minute lunch breaks. i really cant now. did you understand whats the problem? I try to type 500 in the first row after first typing 500 in the third row. when i start typing and type 5(which is less than 495), `balanceLeftInExpense` is 495, when I type 0(which is less than 450) next, it is 450. when i try to type 500, the `balanceLeftInExpense` is 450, but 500 is greater than the balance left(450), so I cant type the 0. See my `substring()` validation above

Comment: If I understand you correctly you should check `limitKeyPress`

Comment: @Justcode no, that is not the problem. when the number i type is less than `balanceLeftInExpense ` it allows me to type(limitkeypress limits only if character count = 10)

Comment: You probably shouldn't save the `deductedTillNow`, if you are gonna restrict the input depending on it. Why don't you add the values on every `ng-change`? (Yes, this is a bit slower, but if you are gonna have just a few fields it shouldn't be noticeable)

Comment: @dquijada i'm doing that already? please write as answer. i cant fully understand what you're saying

Comment: @Justcode please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-vc9lg5

Comment: actually I am not getting proper idea what you actually want, you can edit your question and add proper explanation of expected output.

Comment: @Justcode edited the question. have also updated the stackblitz with values from the image

Comment: @Abhi do you want something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-d9lvym

Comment: @Justcode i think that's it. i hope it works in all cases. please write as answer and i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you are checking the balanceleft wrongly

```
 if(item.adjustAmount > item.amount || (item.amount <= 0)){
      item.adjustAmount = null;
      return
    }
```

Balance left should be checked after deducting the amount like this

```
  $scope.balanceLeftInExpense = $scope.totalExpenseAmount - $scope.deductedTillNow;

  if ($scope.balanceLeftInExpense < 0) {
    item.adjustAmount = item.adjustAmount.toString();
    item.adjustAmount = item.adjustAmount.substring(0, item.adjustAmount.length - 1);
    item.adjustAmount = parseInt(item.adjustAmount);
  }
```

And account disable code seems also wrong where you need to check each row with its data
You should check it like this for each row with its expenses

```
  //if amount entered is equal to advance paid of that row, enable others
  for (let i = 0; i < $scope.amountLedgerListArray.length; i++) {
    if (Number($scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].amount) < $scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].adjustAmount) {
      $scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].isDisabled = false;
    }
    else {         
        //disable those that dont have a value in it
        if ($scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].advance_id != item.advance_id && !$scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].adjustAmount && Number($scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].amount) < $scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].adjustAmount) {
          $scope.amountLedgerListArray[i].isDisabled = true;           

      }
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-d9lvym), you do not need to disable the textbox as your check doesn't allow to enter.

Comment: i dont understand the last part "When account disable code..". I think you have pasted my code...i dont see any difference in the last part

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to following:

```
if(($scope.totalExpenseAmount <= $scope.deductedTillNow) || (($scope.totalExpenseAmount - $scope.deductedTillNow) < item.adjustAmount) ){
  item.adjustAmount = item.adjustAmount.toString();
  item.adjustAmount = item.adjustAmount.substring(0, item.adjustAmount.length - 1);
  item.adjustAmount = parseInt(item.adjustAmount);
}
```